# Open ports/port forwarding with Open.NAT

Tags: c#, port, portforwarding, upnp, miniupnpc

I'm trying to create a simple program that with a click will open/forward some ports without the need to do it every time in the console.

Well I know two different projects to open ports, the first one is called "upnpc" -> http://miniupnp.free.fr/files/, but have to do it manually for every port or the second one a lib which can be used in C# -> https://github.com/lontivero/Open.NAT.

First method is to create a script and to call it with C# but I think is not a good idea.

```
upnpc-shared -a 192.168.1.12 6622 6622 TCP
```

The second with the lib there something that can't figure out why isn't working.

Here's my code which should open/forward 3 ports, but only the last one works.
P.s. I think it opens the ports one by one but for some reason only the last one seems to work, the others stop.

```
public static void Main()
{
    OpenPort().Wait();

    Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static async Task OpenPort()
{
    var nat = new NatDiscoverer();
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(5000);
    var device = await nat.DiscoverDeviceAsync(PortMapper.Upnp, cts);
    var ip = await device.GetExternalIPAsync();

    Console.WriteLine("Your IP: {0}", ip);

    await device.CreatePortMapAsync(new Mapping(Protocol.Tcp, 6622, 6622, 0, "port 6622"));
    await device.CreatePortMapAsync(new Mapping(Protocol.Tcp, 6625, 6625, 0, "port 6625"));
    await device.CreatePortMapAsync(new Mapping(Protocol.Tcp, 6626, 6626, 0, "port 6626"));
    Console.WriteLine("Done!");
}
```

Don't know why doesn't work and have no idea how to make it works for all ports. Hope someone will show me the proper way to do this task.

Comment: Hi beBoss, Open.NAT maintainer here. Please fiil an issue in github for help, I think your tool worth it.